# "Class 'Cpdf' not found" in "develop" branch

Tags: php, dompdf

I am trying to pull in the develop branch, using composer, like this:

```
"require": {
    "dompdf/dompdf" : "dev-develop"
}
```

And requiring like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Dompdf/Dompdf;
// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once 'vendor/dompdf/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';
```

But I am getting error:

```
 Fatal error: Class 'Cpdf' not found in /vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf/Adapter/CPDF.php on line 190
```

Line 190:

```
    $this->_pdf = new \Cpdf(
```

Comment: Can you open the CPDF.php and add \ infront of the class call? Like "new \CPDF. Just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks - but it already has that.

Comment: Is the "use Dompdf/Dompdf" mandatory? Are you using namespaces in your project?

Comment: No, I am not using namespaces. In the stable 0.6 branch the `use Dompdf` is not necessary, but in the "develop" one, it will otherwise fail saying "Class Dompdf not found`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would recommend not use develop branch. Please try:

```
$ composer require "dompdf/dompdf" "0.6.*"
```

Than in or class add:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);
define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php';


$pdf = new Cpdf();
```

The issue is the class `\Cpdf` is not defined in a namespace so composer does not include it in `.\vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php` so `require` need to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Loading an elder commit solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me

1. composer remove barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
2. composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
3. composer update
4. composer install

Note, laravel use 5.5.

If you are on Laravel, remember to include it in /config/app.php

Provider:
Barryvdh \ DomPDF \ ServiceProvider :: class,

and

Aliases:
'PDF' => Barryvdh \ DomPDF \ Facade :: class,